# Python Multiprocessing for a Single Output File (CSV)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am looking for some good example code of MultiProcessing in Python that would take in a large array (broken into different sections of the same main array) to speed up the processing of the subsequent Output file.  I am noticing that there are other things like Lock() functions to make sure it comes back in a certain order but not a good example of how to get the resulting arrays back out when the jobs are run so I can output a single CSV file in the correct time series order.

Below is what I have been working with so far with the queue.  How can one assign the results of q1.get() or others to recombine later?  It just spins when I try assigning it with temp = q1.get()...  And good examples of splitting out an array, sending it to multiple processes, then recombining the results of the function(s) called would be appreciated.  I am using Python 3.7 and Windows 10.

```
import time
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def f1(q, testArray):
    testArray2 = [[41, None, 'help'], [42, None, 'help'], [43, None, 'help']]
    testArray =  testArray + testArray2
    q.put(testArray)

def f2(q, testArray):
    #testArray.append([43, None, 'goodbye'])
    testArray =  testArray + ([44, None, 'goodbye'])
    q.put(testArray)
    return testArray

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Number of cpu : ", multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    testArray1 = [1]
    testArray2 = [2]
    q1 = Queue()
    q2 = Queue()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=f1, args=(q1, testArray1,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=f2, args=(q2, testArray2,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()   

    print(q1.get())      # prints whatever you set in function above
    print(q2.get())      # prints whatever you set in function above
    
    print(testArray1)
    print(testArray2)

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Comment: better use `multiprocessing.Pool` and you get result in correct order.

Comment: there is no need to use queue for this example - simply use `return` for this. You have only two procesess assingned to `p1`, `p2` so you can easily control order - first `p1` and later `p2`

Comment: if you would have more complex example then you can enumerate data (assign numbers to data) and send data with this number, and later send back result with the same number - and then you can use this number to keep order.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you only need one queue for all of your processes. The queue is designed for inter-process communication.

For the ordering you can pass in a process id and sort based on that after the results are joined. Or you can try and use multiprocessing pool as furas suggests.

Which sounds like a better approach. Worker pools in general allocate a pool of workers up front then run a set of jobs on the pool. This is more efficient because the processes / threads are set up initially and reused for jobs. Where your implementation is going the process is created per job / function which is costly depending on how much data you're crunching.